# Block access to specifc attribute inside own class

Tags: java, lambda, annotations, thread-safety, access-modifiers

I'm using a public java API to build my multi thread application, but I don't know if some methods of this API are thread-safe [indeed I really think they aren't].

I was looking for the most clean and straight way to implement this safety on my code and decided to use lambda expression.

I'm planning to use something like this:

```
public class Myclass {

    private NotThreadSafe obj;

    public Myclass() {
        this.obj = new NotThreadSafe();
    }

    private synchronized void useNonThreadSafeObject(FunctionalInterface r) {
        r.exec(this.obj);
    }

    private void method1() {
        this.useNonThreadSafeObject((NotThreadSafe p)->{/*do stuff*/};);
    }

    private void method2() {
        this.obj.someMethod();
    }
    /* any other methods */
}
```

**I want to make sure that no method in  Myclass will call directly to 'obj'**

so all methods must use obj as method1 do, avoiding directly call as method2

of course java doens't have a modifier to do it, but I was wondering if was an annotation or other way to check it at compiler time...

----[I wasn't clear at first time, trying to explain more]----

Comment: What's r? In what way does it guarantee thread safety that synchronized already doesn't?

Comment: @mk that's not actually an answer to my question.

Comment: @pvg It lets you pass in arbitrary code which will operate on `apiObjectNonThreadSafeObject`. The alternative is to expose `apiObjectNonThreadSafeObject`, but then there is no guarantee that the code using it will wrap it with `synchronize`.

Comment: @mk seems pretty pointless since you can just pass whatever you need to nonThreadSafedoodad. method call is already synchronized, the lambda buys you nothing but lack of clarity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply split the class into two:

```
class Guard {
  private final NotThreadSafe obj;

  public Guard() {
      this.obj = new NotThreadSafe();
  }

  synchronized void useNonThreadSafeObject(FunctionalInterface r) {
      r.exec(this.obj);
  }
}
public class Myclass {
  private Guard guard=new Guard();

  private void method1() {
      guard.useNonThreadSafeObject(p -> {/*do stuff with p*/});
  }

  private void method2() {
      guard.useNonThreadSafeObject(p->{/*do other stuff with p*/});
  }

  /* any other methods */

}
```

This is the best isolation you can get as no direct access to `obj` is possible from `MyClass`. But note that this is not bullet-proof, it’s still possible to create a custom implementation of `FunctionalInterface` which will keep the received `NotThreadSafe` instance and store it somewhere in the heap for accessing it at a later time without the `Guard`. However, that’s a bigger effort and unlikely to happen accidentally…